# Obtaining pygeostat?

Tags: python

I have been trying to use the [pygeostat](http://www.ccgalberta.com/pygeostat/installation.html), it seems to me that they need `userid/password` when trying to download package from [Geostatistics Knowledge Base](https://ccgsrv.geostats.ualberta.ca/ccgkb/doku.php). But I could not find the contact information for this.

Comment: That's because the developer doesn't release it to the public yet. I talked to their team leader yesterday. He inferd that he doesn't think there is any reason to make the whole project open source and free to users, because he has some students to pay salary to and they are funded by private company which may not provide money if they can get free code anyway. So, maybe we can write an open source alternative module. I will try to do that next year.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a useful library.

It isn't on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) so it won't be possible to **pip install** it.

However that page mentions a **conda** package. This will need [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which is a python / R platform for scientific use. That might be something to try first. I haven't tried this, I just use plain old Python.

It looks as if they might be in the process of putting it on GitHub but there's [currently just a licence and no code](https://github.com/centre-computational-geostatistics)

However there are [contact details on the home page](https://ccgsrv.geostats.ualberta.ca/).